# Why double toggle on the same page request double click?

Tags: jquery

this is my first question on stack, i have this html/jQuery:

```js
$("#mdrop1").toggle(function() {

  $("#mt1").slideDown();
  $("#mt2").slideUp();

}, function() {
  $("#mt1").slideUp()

});

$("#mdrop2").toggle(function() {

  $("#mt2").slideDown();
  $("#mt1").slideUp();
}, function() {
  $("#mt2").slideUp()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="mdrop2">dropdown 2</a>
<div class="dropdown-laterale" id="mt2">
  <a href="menu1.html">menu 1</a>
  <a href="menu2.html">menu 2</a>
  <a href="menu3.html">menu 3</a>
</div>
<hr>
<a href="#" id="mdrop1">dropdown 1</a>
<div class="dropdown-laterale" id="mt1">
  <a href="othermenu1.html">other menu 1</a>
  <a href="othermenu2.html">other menu 2</a>
  <a href="othermenu3.html">other menu 3</a>
</div>
<hr>
```

The first time that i click `#mdrop1` with `#mt2` opened, `$mt2` slideup correctly and the same behavior is when i click `#mdrop2` with `#mt1` already open BUT... if i want to repeat my action on these 2 toggles they work only with double click... why??
I hope my explanation is clear :)

Comment: I tried your code and it just toggles mdrop elements, as it is supposed to. Where is your onclick event? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not very clear actually, if you want to toggle the menus on click i think you should use `$('#mt1').click(function(){....})` instead. View more about on click actions here
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Besides, your code for toggle is not correct, you cannot pass 2 callback functions to it, jquery doesn't support that, refer to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, the thing that i want to do is that when i open one menu other menu, if already opened, it  close

Comment: as explained above, you need to use jquery's `click`, not `toggle`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this solution:

```js
$('#mdrop1').click(function(){
   
   if ( $('#mt1').css('display') == 'none' ){
       $("#mt1").slideDown();
    
     if ( $('#mt2').css('display') == 'block' )
     {
      $("#mt2").slideUp();
     }
   }
   else
   {
    $("#mt1").slideUp();
   }
  
  });
  
  $('#mdrop2').click(function(){
   
   if ( $('#mt2').css('display') == 'none' ){
       $("#mt2").slideDown();
    
     if ( $('#mt1').css('display') == 'block' )
     {
      $("#mt1").slideUp();
     }
   }
   else
   {
    $("#mt2").slideUp();
   }
  
  });
```